# sound in firefox via ssh -X

Tags: ssh, audio, firefox

I have a headless debian box with speakers. Suppose I'm at my laptop and I do

> $ ssh headless -X
>
> $ audacious

then audacious' window pops up on my laptop's screen. If I open a file then it is played on the speakers connected to headless (as expected). The same behaviour happens with mplayer (i.e. sound is played on the speakers of headless).

However, when I do

> $ ssh headless -X
>
> $ firefox

and play a sound on wikipedia or a video on youtube then the sound is played on my laptop's speakers.

This is unexpected and undesirable. How can I get firefox to use headless' speakers just like other programs do?

Both my laptop and headless use alsa (without pulseaudio), both are up-to-date debian wheezy machines.

Comment: Check this: http://superuser.com/questions/231920/forwarding-audio-like-x-in-ssh

Comment: Are you sure that firefox runs on headless, normally when you do a stunt like this firefox run on laptop even though you started it on headless. Try 'ssh other_user@headless -X'

Comment: @a21: I'm left speechless - you're right! Why does it happen? How do I prevent it?

Comment: @a21 Thanks, I think it would take me years to figure out firefox actually doesn't run on headless...

Answer (score 1):

As explained by a21 above, what happened is that firefox, rather surprisingly, in fact runs on laptop, not headless! The reasons and a solution is described here:
[Starting firefox on a remote host (over ssh) opens a new window locally: what is happening?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2794/starting-firefox-on-a-remote-host-over-ssh-opens-a-new-window-locally-what-is?rq=1)